# Ajax() response not received on time?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have tried too many codes to achieve the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var json_data = $.getJSON('url_to_json_encoded_array.php',function(j){
                 return j;
              });
         });
   if(json_data.length > 0){
            //fetch data from the json_data json ecoded array here

       }
```

But after running the code I always get json_data is with no data, while in developer tab -> network-> i can see that the data loaded in proper mode....

php code which returning the json encoded array is as following:

```
    <?php 
           echo(json_encode(array("name"=>$name,"email"=>$email)));
     ?>
```

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is async, you will receive your data inside the callback function

```
$.getJSON('url_to_json_encoded_array.php', function(data) {
  // here you have it
  console.log(data);
});
```